# Better than Rembrandt

Tags: visual, rebus, geography, nonogram

<sub>This puzzle is part 13 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > Today I visited a certain tall building. Not recommended if you're afraid of heights! In the evening I'm planning to watch a light show. This marks the half-way point of my trip, so plenty of places left to visit. Take care!
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]
>   ([alternate version with colours labelled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yyZU.png))

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[A game of cricket](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84078)*".</sub>

Comment: Would you happen to have a colour-blind friendly version of this? I don't do too well when a lot of colours are involved in something.

Comment: Could you confirm that the numbers in column 6 are correct? They seem inconsistent with one obvious guess at how the puzzle works. Of course that _could_ just mean that that guess is wrong (or that I can't count)...

Comment: I don’t think it’s that easy @GarethMcCaughan — don’t think there necessarily have to be blank spaces between the colours....but I might be wrong.

Comment: @DanielBaliki Sorry, should have thought about that... I can post the numbers with colour indicators added (e.g. R2 for red 2) when I get to a computer, is that ok?

Comment: @El-Guest That's why I said "one obvious guess"! I agree that everything might well be correct. (But note that most rows _don't_ have enough numbers to fill everything up with no gaps.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Rechecked column 6, those are the correct numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Apologies for my skepticism :-).

Comment: @jafe It's all good. Don't think I'd be able to answer fast enough anyways :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Completed Nonogram:

> [image]

Rebus decoding and final solution:

> Going left to right, the first image is a frog then -F so **rog**. The next image is the symbol for internet explorer, so we use **ie** from initials? Next looks to be a rat -A so **rt**. Not sure for the next one but based on help from @athin cow  -C so **ow**. Next is the note E +R so **er**. Put all together you get **Rogier Tower**.

Comment: The final answer should be ROT13(Ebtvre Gbjre) :)

Comment: I think that's RAT - A, not R

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Yeah that was a typo fixed now