# A game of cricket

Tags: geography, grid-deduction, slitherlink

<sub>This puzzle is part 14 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > You may not know this about me, but I'm quite the sports fan. Today I went to watch a match at a local cricket ground. Not every stop on the trip needs to be the Great Wall of China or the Grand Canyon, wouldn't you agree? Sometimes it's fun to just get to know new people and take it easy for a while.
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]

Hint:

> There is a tag missing.

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[Moons and messages](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84136)*".</sub>

Comment: may i ask if my slitherlink is correct? thx!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Yep!

Comment: is that the 'sudoku' tag?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Ixnay on the oilerspay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on

> @JonMark Perry's comment and @Omega Krypton's slitherlink solution, I have the following: [image: Gladys double sudoku]

You are thus at

> [Ransomes Sports Pavilion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ransomes_and_Reavell_Sports_Club_Ground), in Ipswich! [Found by taking the highlighted letters in yellow from left to right and top down.]

Comment: nice finding +1!

Comment: @jafe what are the colours for then?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I think they are to rot13(qryvarngr gung gurer ner gjb qvssrerag fhqbxhf gb or fbyirq, naq gung jr fubhyqa'g zvk gurz jura fbyivat gur fhqbxh cbegvba.)

Comment: oh... i see... nice one!

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer

slitherlink part:

> [image]