# ...And they were stumped for a long time

Tags: knowledge, geography, crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part 16 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > Today I got a glimpse of what things may have looked like on Earth millions of years ago.
> >
> > I'm debating whether I should give you a hint about today's puzzle or not. If it was anyone else I would try to point them into the right direction, but you, dear Puzzling, can probably work it out on your own. After all, I assume you have at least some interest in geography if you've followed my journey this far.
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]
>
> 1. Loop of rope / Shakespeare's pentameter
>   2. Technically just outside Las Vegas / Chameleon or gecko
>   3. Ground spice / E-book reader
>   4. String instrument / Time travel film
>   5. Inexpensive / Llama relative
>   6. Fossilized resin / Native American or South Asian
>   7. Brownish colour / Immigrants
>   8. Vagabond / Extreme stupidity
>   9. Riddermark / Very young child
>   10. Lanzhou's province / Worshipped at Delphi
>   11. Accepted in Greek and Irish shops / Light phenomenon

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[A burglar's sunglasses, a lady's odyssey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84187)*".</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gladys is in

> **FOSSIL GROVE**

The grid:

> [image]

1. Loop of rope / Shakespeare's pentameter

   > **L**ASSO / IAMBI**C**
2. Technically just outside Las Vegas / Chameleon or gecko

   > S**T**RIP / LIZA**R**D
3. Ground spice / E-book reader

   > CU**M**IN / KIN**D**LE
4. String instrument / Time travel film

   > CEL**L**O / LO**O**PER
5. Inexpensive / Llama relative

   > CHEA**P** / A**L**PACA
6. Fossilized resin / Native American or South Asian

   > AMBER / **I**NDIAN
7. Brownish colour / Immigrants

   > KHAK**I** / A**L**IENS
8. Vagabond / Extreme stupidity

   > NOM**A**D / ID**I**OCY
9. Riddermark / Very young child

   > RO**H**AN / INF**A**NT
10. Lanzhou's province / Worshipped at Delphi

    > G**A**NSU / APOL**L**O
11. Accepted in Greek and Irish shops / Light phenomenon

    > **E**UROS / AUROR**A**

The middles ...

> are capital cities, if you take some letters from the left and right. So:
>
>  SOFIA, Bulgaria
>  TRIPOLI, Libya
>  MINSK, Belarus
>  OSLO, Norway
>  APIA, Samoa
>  BERLIN, Germany
>  KIGALI, Rwanda
>  MADRID, Spain
>  HANOI, Vietnam
>  SUVA, Fiji
>  ROSEAU, Dominica

Comment: I had [rot13]ncbyyb for 10 and [rot13]pbeban for 11 but I think your 11 fits better.

Comment: "Outside Las Vegas" is [rot13]FGEVC.  Beyond that, I'm not sure...

Comment: @Exal Thanks, I wasn't coming up with anything useful there.

Comment: Here I was thinking that  "Alpaca" was somehow wrong when "Apia" was staring me right in the face on the top of the capitals list!

Comment: Hehee...  looks like @Jay was right about 10.

Comment: Nice work! And here I was thinking how to word the hint I was going to give after 24 hours...

Comment: @jafe Another great puzzle. I love this series :)

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer, going off the full answer chart:

> Each pair of answers, when a letter is put in the middle, creates a city, probably a capital city--four thus far...  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer

1

> Lasso, iambic