# A burglar's sunglasses, a lady's odyssey

Tags: wordplay, geography, crossword-clues

<sub>This puzzle is part 17 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > I hope that you are well. Today I listened to some wonderful classical music, played in an extremely impressive setting. While going to concerts is something that I can do at home as well, being in an exciting new place somehow makes the whole experience so much better.
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.
> >
> > P.S. Looking for one word of 15 letters!

> A part of the arm (5),
>   a continent's highest mountain (6),
>   an Australian capital (9),
>   a gardening tool (11)
>
> A sea mammal (7),
>   an Egyptian riddler (6),
>   a form of carbon (8),
>   an online scamming technique (8)
>
> A Himalayan city (5),
>   Viking afterlife (8),
>   hotheaded, reckless (9),
>   a maritime punishment (11)
>
> A protective covering (6),
>   a Joseph Smith follower (6),
>   a state of confusion (7),
>   a state that borders Canada (7)
>
> A female relative (5),
>   a spirit in a lamp (5),
>   a man in a lion's den (6),
>   merciful, tolerant (7)

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[On a puzzling spree](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84214)*".</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gladys is at

> [Elbphilharmonie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbphilharmonie)

A part of the arm (5),
a continent's highest mountain (6),
an Australian capital (9),
a gardening tool (11)

> **Elb**ow, **Elb**rus, M**elb**ourne, Whe**elb**arrow

A sea mammal (7),
an Egyptian riddler (6),
a form of carbon (8),
an online scamming technique (8)

**Solved by Omega Krypton**

> dol**phi**n, s**phi**nx, gra**phi**te, **phi**shing

A Himalayan city (5),
Viking afterlife (8),
hotheaded, reckless (9),
a maritime punishment (11)

> **Lha**sa, Va**lha**lla, Foo**lha**rdy, Kee**lha**uling

A protective covering (6),
a Joseph Smith follower (6),
a state of confusion (7),
a state that borders Canada (7)

> A**rmo**ur, Mo**rmo**n,  tu**rmo**il, Ve**rmo**nt

A female relative (5),
a spirit in a lamp (5),
a man in a lion's den (6),
merciful, tolerant (7)

> **Nie**ce, Ge**nie**, Da**nie**l, le**nie**nt

Comment: nice answer, +1!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Thanks, I gave you +1 also as you solved the second section before I did.

Comment: thanks, to be honest, i have no idea how you can solve the rest... kudos to you!

Answer (score 4):

Partial

A sea mammal (7),
an Egyptian riddler (6),
a form of carbon (8),
an online scamming technique (8)

> dolphin, sphinx, graphite, phishing