# On a puzzling spree

Tags: knowledge, crosswords, word-search

<sub>This puzzle is part 18 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > I had a big, history-themed tour today. There are so many fascinating things to see that it can get pretty overwhelming.
> >
> > I have to admit that lately I've been spending a lot of time on a relatively small area. I have to pick up the pace a little for the rest of the trip. The final destination is still far away.
> >
> > The answer to this one consists of two common 6-letter words. Have fun!
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Required for shooting
>   5. Webpage styling
>   8. Elementary's Watson
>   9. Where Europe ends
>   10. Not least
>   11. A long-legged Australian
>   12. Spoken in Southern China
>   14. King of tragedy
>   16. Not Unix
>   18. Gandalf actor and 007 creator
>   21. Between ready and fire
>   22. Dracula heroine
>   23. Knife strike
>   24. Parental Arabic letter
>
> **Down**
>   1. The enemy of my enemy
>   2. Disappeared soldier
>   3. Personified inspiration
>   4. Not closeted
>   5. A First Nation
>   6. Halfling gardener
>   7. Insult
>   13. A foot or a stone
>   14. A foot or a hand
>   15. Fell for Vronsky
>   16. Type of astronomical giant
>   17. Danced with John to Chuck Berry
>   19. – and abet
>   20. Unhappy Arabic letter

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[Drums and punctuation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84221)*".</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]
>  I've highlighted the two words making up the solution: **MUSEUM ISLAND**.

Some feedback on crossword cluing:

> A lot of the clues don't really work according to regular crossword rules -- they describe actions that specific people do or qualities that something has, but don't really define it. For example, "Required for shooting" cluing AMMO -- that should be "*Thing* required for shooting". AMMO is a noun, so the clue has to be a noun too: in crosswords, clues should match in part of speech. Several of the clues here have this problem: 1A, 12A, 16A, 21A, 15D, and 17D.
>
>  Also, 2D and 5D have the opposite problems (cluing adjective answers as if they were nouns).
>
>  Some other nitpicks: Clues that define by examples (like 18A, 13D, and 14D) need to have something along the lines of "..., maybe", "..., perhaps", or "..., for some" at the end as well. 1D is a bit questionable as well, because the phrase being referred to specifically does not end in "ally".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll go through my clues for the upcoming ones one more time... The same issues probably show up in some of those. The answer's correct, of course.