# Drums and punctuation

Tags: wordplay, pattern, geography, crossword-clues

<sub>This puzzle is part 19 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > I have finally come back to a bit of a warmer climate. I haven't really had a chance to properly work on my tan just yet, so today I went to the beach to get some sun. I might even book myself a treatment at the spa. After that it's again time to get my passport ready for the next flight...
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> 1. A Scandinavian name (not a computer brand) [1,2]
> 2. A scapegoat (not speedy) [3,4]
> 3. Collections (not a short time, abbreviated) [2,4]
> 4. A South African language (not a Cuban drum) [1,6]
> 5. Diverse or various, briefly (not fogs) [1,2]
> 6. A Pixar film (not monarchs) [1,3]
> 7. A physician, colloquially (not punctuation signs) [2]
> 8. Scatterbrained (not dangerous or uncertain) [1,2,4]
> 9. Holes in the ground (not an image, in short) [3]
> 10. A curve (not creative activities) [2]
> 11. Thus written (not "is seated") [2,3]
> 12. Tiny (not frosty) [2]

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[Lady G's amazing mazings](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84259)*".</sub>

Comment: is it hole or holes for 9?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton #9 is holes, plural.

Comment: is the place 21 letters long? thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gladys is in

> the [Matsesta Microdistrict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsesta_Microdistrict).

Explanation:

> ```
> MATS not MAC     1,2 MA
> PATSY not PACY   3,4 TS
> SETS not SEC     2,4 ES
> TSONGA not CONGA 1,6 TA
> MISC not MISTS   1,2 MI
> CARS not TSARS   1,3 CR
> DOC not DOTS     2   O
> DITSY not DICY   1,2,DIS
> PITS not PIC     3   T
> ARC not ARTS     2   R
> SIC not SITS     2,3 IC
> ITSY not ICY     2   T
> ```

where

> each "X not Y" is a word meaning X in which we can replace C with TS or vice versa to get a word meaning Y; we then extract letters at the given positions.

Credit where due:

> Jay and Omega Krypton solved some of the clues before I did, though as it happens I didn't look at their answers.

Comment: Do you have the correlation to the title?

Comment: I thought it was just because one of the clues mentions drums and another mentions punctuation. If there's something more than that then no, I don't have it.

Comment: Ok thanks. Wasn't sure if the specific substitution was relatable. Good work nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

Only a partial answer

> 1.  ivan (not ibm)
>  2.
>  3.  sets (not secs)
>  4.  kongo (not conga)
>  5.  misc (not mists)
>  6.  cars (not czars)
>  7.  doc (not dots)
>  8.
>  9.
>  10. arc (not art)
>  11. sic (not sit)
>  12.

Comment: what do you think the numbers in square brackets are? btw, nice answer, +1!

Comment: for 7 maybe add 's' after the t? (plural)

Comment: I'm not sure about the numbers, I was hoping it would help to spell something meaningful. I'm not sure if all of these are right so far.

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer

9

> pits (not pic)