# Lady G's amazing mazings

Tags: geography, cryptic-clues, mazes, cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part 20 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > My passport keeps filling up with new stamps. Hopefully I have enough pages left to finish the trip. Today I visited a museum detailing the history of an industry which has been especially important in this part of the world. I hope to write to you again soon.
> >
> > The word borders in the crossword form a maze. Remember, every square is reachable from the start!
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]
>
> **Across** (unordered)
>   1. Unit surrounded by falsehood – first signs of trouble (5)
>   2. Ancient France's global borders holding precious metal (4)
>   3. Anxiety as Swiss physics lab is associated with scam (7)
>   4. Woman is initially fearful before programme's ending (5)
>   5. Clothing for unruly Thai around Burmese capital (5)
>   6. Tenant's point of view in payment to landlord (8)
>   7. Behind the freaky boat, nothing is forbidden (5)
>   8. Breathe, former lover! Heal unexpectedly! (6)
>   9. Cops confused by the end, to some extent (5)
>   10. Clothing for unnoted hunting expedition (4)
>   11. Scottish king buried in walled garden (5)
>   12. Greasy ornamental mat has no front (4)
>   13. Man's postal delivery called out (4)
>   14. Scrape up cardroom's commission (4)
>   15. Polish back of heavy stone (4)
>
> **Down** (unordered)
>   1. Leave, clutching unfinished plot to take advantage of (7)
>   2. Outlandish ransom off historically powerful Russians (9)
>   3. Country's central palace in the middle of puddle (6)
>   4. Determine the age of heartless Italian poet (4)
>   5. Intelligence operative is a well-mannered man (5)
>   6. Charitable donations essential to Palm Sunday (4)
>   7. Baku – abnormally large capital (5)
>   8. Perish by the end of strict regimen (4)
>   9. State to ban possessing one top hat (5)
>   10. Seashore to be a march's ending (5)
>   11. President's mother cooked corn (6)
>   12. Ohio's banks yearn for tea (6)
>   13. Landform or Arizona city (4)

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[A fortified nonogram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84266)*".</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The grid:

> [image]

The location:

> The solution to the maze is the highlighted cells in the above image, which spell **OMAN OIL AND GAS EXHIBITION CENTRE**.

Individual clue explanations:

> I use standard(-ish) cryptic annotations here: the capital letters by themselves are the solution word, and the punctuation and lowercase letters tell how it is assembled.
>
>   **Across:**
>      1: LI(TR)E
>      2: G(AU)L
>      3: CON+CERN (reverse order?)
>      4: FE_ + _MME (multiple heads/tails?)
>      5: HA(B)IT*
>      6: RE(SIDE)NT
>      7: TABO*+O
>      8: EX+HALE*
>      9: SCOP*+_E
>      10: SA(-fa)RI
>      11: _ED GAR_
>      12: (-d)OILY
>      13: MALE ("mail")
>      14: RAKE (double def)
>      15: RUB+_Y
>   **Down:**
>      1: EX(PLO(-t))IT
>      2: ROMANOFFS*
>      3: PO(_LA_)ND
>      4: DA(-n)TE
>      5: A+GENT
>      6: _ALMS_
>      7: KABU*+L
>      8: DIE+_T
>      9: B(I+H_)AR
>      10: BE + A + _CH (using "ending" for two letters again, and an extra "to"?)
>      11: MA+CRON*
>      12: O_O+LONG
>      13:  MESA (double def)

Comment: All correct, nice job! Re: reverse order in 3a - I thought it was ok to change the order of the terms in formulations like "A <next to> B" as long as the indicator doesn't determine a specific order (before/after, over/under etc)?

Comment: @jafe I don't think I've ever seen it used in a clue before this -- I think general convention is that concatenation indicators are always left-to-right unless otherwise specified? But I could be wrong, and it could just be an uncommon thing.

Answer (score 5):

Another partial answer:

Across

1. > 
2. > Gaul
3. > Concern
4. > Femme
5. > Habit
6. > Resident
7. > Taboo
8. > Exhale
9. > 
10. > 
11. > 
12. > Oily
13. > 
14. > 
15. > 

Down

1. > Exploit
2. > 
3. > Poland
4. > Date
5. > Agent
6. > Alms
7. > Kabul
8. > Diet
9. > 
10. > 
11. > 
12. > Oolong
13. > Mesa

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer

A12

> OILY (DOILY - D, def: greasy)

D13

> MESA (double def)