# A fortified nonogram

Tags: visual, geography, sequence, nonogram

<sub>This puzzle is part 21 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > Today I went to see a royal palace, a Hindu temple, and some wonderful gardens, all within an enormous military fortress. The view from up here is amazing. The end of my trip is already approaching all too quickly – time flies when you're having fun. I'm still definitely going to try to enjoy my last few destinations to the fullest.
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[Gladys goes shopping](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84303)*".</sub>

Comment: Already filling up half of them and then finding a contradiction, RIP me :(

Comment: I'm finding a contradiction on row 3 so far.. could just be my logic skills though

Comment: Hmm I'll recheck the numbers, just a moment...

Comment: I started again and I definitely made a mistake first time

Comment: Solved the grid, no mistakes in it.

Comment: @wl Alright, thanks. Certainly wouldn't have been the first time I couldn't count to a number below 10...

Comment: This might be too much to ask, but would you gather these series into a pdf/doc file once you are finished? I'd print it so I could guess it in the paper version.

Comment: @ThomasBlue Sure. Just let me know where to send it.

Comment: @jafe You could send it to sirtafeb@gmail.com and I'll probably make a cloud link to post later

Comment: @ThomasBlue You've got mail.

Comment: @jafe Thanks, it's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Gladys is

> at the Mehrangarh fort in Jodhpur in India.

The grid:

> [image]

Transcription:

> 98 / Xp G / I
>  ring / rung
>  G# / Bb Ru / Pd
>  on a background of a blue circle and five red spots (which looks like it should be a national flag but doesn't actually appear to be).
>  We have to fill in gaps. 98 **Me** Xp (MS Windows versions); G **H** I (letters); ring **rang** rung (verb forms); G# **A** Bb (musical notes); Ru **Rh** Pd (chemical elements).
>  Putting the gap-fillers together yields our answer.