# Gladys goes shopping

Tags: knowledge, visual, geography, crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part 22 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > Today I went to a marketplace. I quite like the atmosphere – there are a lot of people and plenty of exciting new things around every corner, even though it's not even the biggest market in town. I can't get too crazy with the shopping here, though. There is another flight ahead, and there's only so much room in my suitcase!
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Part of Zorro's costume
>   5. Family name of an Asian dictator
>   6. Witches' –
>   10. Pole often held up by guys
>   12. Part of the Austrian Alps
>   13. Fictional suitor disliked by Team Edward
>   15. Native of Vietnam's capital
>   18. Jose Cuervo ingredient
>   21. – and flow
>   22. *J'accuse* author
>   23. Unit symbolized by struck-through Y
>   24. Plays on the radio
>   25. Fractions of a euro
>   26. Aquatic organisms
>   28. Area that includes Essen and Dortmund
>   29. Dissuade, discourage
>
> **Down**
>   2. Resource that comes in rounds
>   3. Volvo's former competitor
>   4. Ritually clean
>   6. Family name of an European dictator
>   7. Russian administrative division
>   8. Hold in high esteem
>   9. Two-time Rock and Roll Hall of Fame inductee
>   11. Whitespace characters
>   13. Rapper -Z
>   14. Unfounded rumour
>   16. "Peacock network"
>   17. Mathematician with a beautiful mind
>   19. Regard highly, hold dear
>   20. Number of harvestman's legs
>   27. Father of a tribe of mythological warriors

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[Scripture and yachting](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84391)*".</sub>

Comment: I love this puzzle series. Each one is so simple and original. The difficulty is just enough to give you some idea of which direction to progress, but still teases the brain very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I deserve none of the credit, because @Jay, @Rand, and @Stewie did all of the work. That said,

> I think (based on @Jay’s completed crossword and subsequent Rubik’s cube shift) that if you take the green box only...

Gladys is at

> [Osh Bazaar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osh_Bazaar) in Bishkek, Kyrgyzstan. Note that it is indeed not even the biggest market in Bishkek — that distinction belongs to [Dordoy Bazaar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dordoy_Bazaar), a market on par with some of the biggest in Asia.

Comment: Oh that's a place? I guess I couldn't see it because I was looking too hard in the wrong area. So obvious now! Nice find +1

Comment: Thanks, @Jay....I was thinking too hard and finally it hit me like a brick haha

Comment: ... accepted? that's it? How were we supposed to guess this among all the other possible anagrams of possible coloured boxes? Why the green one in particular? The ending to this puzzle disappointed me a bit.

Comment: I suppose it’s because there were no anagrams needed for this one, @Randal'Thor ?

Comment: There are still anagrams, because the letters are all over the place in the original crossword. Jay shifted them around to get the neat green box.

Comment: Well yes, but once you perform the Rubik’s Cube transformations the answer spells itself out in order in that neat green box.

Answer (score 12):

Partial answer:

The completed crossword looks like this

> [image]

By

> Sliding a row to the left, and then sliding a column down, and ignoring grey squares,

we get this

> [image]
>  I can see a few words in here but nothing complete.

As usual I have no idea where Gladys is.

Edit:

> I have added a 3d view of the cube in case it helps.
>
>  [image]

Comment: you know that could fold to make a cube

Comment: Not sure what to do next though

Comment: Pink face: Solace, Yellow face: library. Orange face: Cave. Green face: Bar. White face: Hotel ?. The letter A appears in all faces

Answer (score 7):

Almost-complete crossword:

> [image]

(There's a few clues I haven't managed to solve, but I've found all the coloured letters at least.)

Green letters:

> S, A, A, O, H, B, Z, A, R. These letters form OH BAZAARS - she's shopping in a bazaar?

Blue letters:

> I, A, N, A, G, A, N, T, S. These letters form TANS AGAIN - she's in a hot sunny place?

Yellow letters:

> B, B, I, L, U, E, A, R, E. I see BLUE in there, maybe something about the sea?

Red letters:

> A, N, O, O, L, A, S, C, E. These letters form OCEAN LAOS, which could be where she is?

My guess at her location:

> a bazaar in Laos near the sea. Unfortunately, Laos is landlocked :-/

Comment: She could also be [rot13]rngvat Oyhr Oevr jvgu n Tvnag'f Tubfg

Answer (score 7):

I used a lot of time on this, so I have to post the complete crossword:

> [image]

Also, my English isn't that good, so solving crosswords is terribly hard.

Blue colors:

> AGAIANNTS
>  ANGASTINA - Village in Crete
>  
>  TANS AGAIN - Sunny place?
>
>  Anyway, a sunny place?

Green tiles:

> SAAOHARBZ
>
>  There's Sahara in there, but that leaves "boz" or "Zob", and I don't know what that means. Also, "Bazars, Oh"
>
>  In Sahara, or on a Bazar. Likely the second one, since he's shopping.

Red tiles:

> ANO OLA SCE: 
>  OCEAN ALSO, Canoe Laos,

Yellow tiles:

> BILUEAREB
>  There are Blue, bar,

In summary:

> There's SAHARA, BLUE, OCEAN ALSO, TANS AGAIN. My guess is: He's in a place where the Sahara meets the Ocean. That's as far as I get at the moment.