# Scripture and yachting

Tags: geography, crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part 23 of **Gladys' journey across the globe**. Each part can be solved independently. Nevertheless, if you are new to the series, feel free to start at the beginning: *[Introducing Gladys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83507)*.</sub>

---

> > Dear Puzzling,
> >
> > You'd think that after so many days on the road I couldn't wait to get back home, but I'm not at all looking forward to the end of my trip. Today I visited an ancient Buddhist temple for some much needed peace and quiet. Only two more destinations left...
> >
> > Wish you were here!
> >     Love, Gladys.

> [image]

---

<sub>Gladys will return in "*[Crossword gone overboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84406)*".</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> [**WOLONG TEMPLE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolong_Temple)

Completed crossword

> [image]
>  Hopefully the extraction is obvious. Most clues are also pretty straightforward. For the ones that aren't straight dictionary definitions... "O, N and He" are periodic table elements oxygen, nitrogen and helium respectively (which are all gasses in STP). That's a map of Benin, a flag of the USA, and a clock face representing 12:00, which could be noon (or midnight). Pep Guardiola, Jacques Tati, Edgar Winter and Johnny Winter are people. Ringo (Starr) is part of the Beatles. Rio refers to Rio de Janeiro which hosted the 2016 Summer Olympics. The River Ob is a river in Siberia. Pot is an informal term for cannabis. Notre precedes Dame to make a phrase.

Answer (score 3):

Glady's in:

> [Wolong Temple](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g298557-d1801446-Reviews-Wolong_Temple-Xi_an_Shaanxi.html) in China.

The completed crossword:

> [image]

I had a hard time with

> Vessel for winter yachting - I've never heard of an iceboat before, but it was the only thing that fit.

The other clues were quite straight forward (with some googling). I finally got to use my ability to recognize any country by its shape and neighboring countries (I'll admit, I sometimes strike out on island states).