# The Video Gamers' Double-Duty Crossword 2

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, cryptic-clues, video-games, crossword-clues

*See the original* [HERE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81324/the-video-gamers-double-duty-crossword)

**Video games — Trivia vs Wordplay — one more time:**

Here are twenty crossword clues that describe twenty video games. Solve them if you'd like!  Or, if you treat each clue as cryptic wordplay (without a def), you'll find a **different** video game is the answer for each clue. When you get all forty written down, put the highlighted letters together to get one last clue. Which type of clue is that one?  You'll see!

| CLUE | CROSSWORD # | CRYPTIC # |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cataclysms? Ultimately, war is not changed | 12 | 6 |
| Snag criminals, swinging around megalopolis center | 9 | 2 |
| Fix or reorganize troubled heads, regularly seeing anxieties | 23 | 8 |
| Intense acrobatics after time's passage gets reversed | 24 | 20 |
| Building a neighborhood starts with some banter and a bunch of animals on deserted isle | 32 | 30 |
| A photo-led horror-show? | 26 | 27 |
| Caught in a misty development — investigation starts within | 29 | 19 |
| One hundred, then ten, fighting to one? Deep trouble. | 1 | 11 |
| Wandering batty around one asylum's origin | 4 | 5 |
| Twisted comedy follows Max's partner to middle of mystery | 10 | 16 |
| Tim's origin (to make a mistake) partly repairable when rewound | 25 | 34 |
| Mafia boss legend stoking gang violence, staging heist | 17 | 3 |
| Partial circle — ravenous head — in clear-out frenzy | 28 | 18 |
| Bring back animated characters from in deserted editor's shed? | 31 | 22 |
| Utter mayhem on roads starts in first place with directionless marsupial | 36 | 39 |
| Decapodan time battle, forgoing artistic limits; a color leads, a color hides. | 33 | 15 |
| Well-timed attack follows dance — lose will to weird musician | 38 | 35 |
| Small rodent returns, starting crude fart adventure | 7 | 14 |
| Start growing! Turn country-side to secure capital before winter begins | 40 | 21 |
| I keep wits about; fungal seed infests and everyone's beginning to disappear | 13 | 37 |

[image: Take 2]

Notes:

> - Names of famous games, game-series, and game subtitles are used. For example, *Ratchet and Clank*, *Ratchet and Clank: Rift Apart* and *Rift Apart* are all acceptable
> - Answers are to be written with no spaces or punctuation
> - this took a really long time to make and I hope there are no mistakes

---

Comment: Never in my wildest dreams have I thought this could be done again, but here we are

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Solved!** The completed grid looks like this:

> [image: Completed grid]

**Clue explanations:**

*Cataclysms? Ultimately, war is not changed*

> Crossword: [**FALLOUT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallout_(series))
>  Cryptic: [**SAINTS ROW**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saints_Row) = _S + WARISNOT*

*Snag criminals swinging around megalopolis center*

> Crossword: [**SPIDERMAN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_in_video_games)
>  Cryptic: [**ANIMAL CROSSING**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Crossing) = SNAGCRIMINALS* around _O_

*Fix or reorganize troubled heads, regularly seeing anxieties*

> Crossword: [**PSYCHONAUTS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychonauts) (suggested by @MOehm in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59744803#59744803))
>  Cryptic: [**FORTNITE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortnite) = F_ O_ R_ T_ + _N_I_T_E_

*Intense acrobatics after time’s passage gets reversed*

> Crossword: [**PRINCE OF PERSIA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia:_The_Sands_of_Time)
>  Cryptic: [**WOLFENSTEIN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfenstein) = FLOW< + INTENSE*

*Building a neighborhood starts with some banter and a bunch of animals on deserted isle*

> Crossword: [**ANIMAL CROSSING**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Crossing) (making a second appearance in the puzzle)
>  Cryptic: [**BANJO-KAZOOIE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banjo-Kazooie) = B_ A_ N_ + JOK(-e) + A ZOO + I(-sl)E

*A photo-led horror-show?*

> Crossword: [**FATAL FRAME**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatal_Frame)
>  Cryptic: [**DEATHLOOP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathloop) = APHOTOLED*

*Caught in a misty development – investigation starts within*

> Crossword: [**SILENT HILL**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Hill)
>  Cryptic: [**SIM CITY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimCity) = MISTY* containing C and I_

*One hundred, then ten, fighting to one? Deep trouble.*

> Crossword: [**BATTLEGROUNDS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayerUnknown%27s_Battlegrounds)
>  Cryptic: [**CENTIPEDE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centipede_(video_game)) = C + TEN* + I + DEEP*

*Wandering batty around one asylum's origin*

> Crossword: [**ARKHAM ASYLUM**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Arkham_Asylum)
>  Cryptic: [**BAYONETTA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayonetta) = BATTY* around ONE + A

*Twisted comedy follows Max's partner to middle of mystery*

> Crossword: [**SAM AND MAX**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_%26_Max#Video_games)
>  Cryptic: [**MINECRAFT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft) = MIN + FARCE< + _T_

*Tim's origin (to make a mistake) partly repairable when rewound*

> Crossword: [**BRAID**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_(video_game))
>  Cryptic: [**TERRARIA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraria) = T_ + ERR + _AIRA_<

*Mafia boss legend, stoking gang violence, staging heist*

> Crossword: [**THE GODFATHER**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather_(2006_video_game)) (thanks to @user39583 in comments)
>  Cryptic: [**DONKEY KONG**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donkey_Kong) = DON + KEY + (-st)OK(-ingag)NG*

*Partial circle – ravenous head – in clear-out frenzy*

> Crossword: [**PAC-MAN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pac-Man)
>  Cryptic: [**FAR CRY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_Cry) = F_Y containing (ARC + R_)

*Bring back animated characters from in deserted editor's shed?*

> Crossword: [**BENDY AND THE INK MACHINE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendy_and_the_Ink_Machine) (thanks to @ShadowCat in comments)
>  Cryptic: [**RESIDENT EVIL**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_Evil) = (LIVE + INDESERT(-ed)*)<

*Utter mayhem on roads starts in first place with directionless marsupial*

> Crossword: [**CRASH TEAM RACING**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_Team_Racing)
>  Cryptic: [**MORTAL KOMBAT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat) = M_ O_ R_ + TALK + (-w)OMBAT *(this is my favourite clue!)*

*Decapodan time battle, forgoing artistic limits; a color leads, a color hides.*

> Crossword: [**SPLATOON**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splatoon)
>  Cryptic: [**RED DEAD REDEMPTION**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dead_Redemption) = RED + DE(-ca)PODANTIME* containing RED

*Well-timed attack follows dance – lose will to weird musician*

> Crossword: [**CRYPT OF THE NECRODANCER**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_of_the_NecroDancer)
>  Cryptic: [**TWISTED METAL**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_Metal) = TWIST + (-w)E(-ll)T(-i)MED + AL (thanks to @fljx in comments)

*Small rodent returns, starting crude fart adventure*

> Crossword: [**CONKER’S BAD FUR DAY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conker%27s_Bad_Fur_Day)
>  Cryptic: [**STARCRAFT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarCraft) = S + RAT< + C_ + FART*

*Start growing! Turn country-side to secure capital before winter begins*

> Crossword: [**STARDEW VALLEY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardew_Valley)
>  Cryptic: [**FALL GUYS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_Guys) = FALL (winter begins, before) + G_ + U (turn) + _Y + S_

*I keep wits about; fungal seed infests and everyone's beginning to disappear*

> Crossword: [**THE LAST OF US**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_of_Us)
>  Cryptic: [**WII SPORTS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Sports) = WITS containing (I + SPOR(-e))

**Final hidden clue:** The final hidden clue shapes up like so (spacing mine):

> BUILD NUMBERS FOR PEACEFUL START INHERITING VARIABLE DOMAIN NEEDING LEADER TWELVE
>
>  The 'TWELVE' at the end represents an enumeration of '(12)' for this final clue. Solving this clue, the final 12-letter video game answer to this metapuzzle is:
>
>  [**CIVILIZATION**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_(video_game)) - clued both straightforwardly by the game's plot *and* cryptically:
>
>  CIVIL ('Build' a word meaning 'peaceful' using Roman numerals) + I_ (start of 'Inheriting') + Z (variable) + (-n)ATION (domain, needing leader)

<sup>*Thanks to @user39583 (#17), @MOehm (#23), @ShadowCat (#31) and @fljx (#35) for their contributions in chat and comments.*</sup>

Comment: I don't really have the domain knowledge for this, but got a few of the cryptics. "Well timed attack ..." is rot13(Gjvfgrq Zrgny - GJVFG + (JRYYGVZRQ - JVYY) + NY (Jrveq Ny) )

Comment: @fljx Ooh, nice spot! Thanks :) Just could not see that one myself!

Comment: I think 17 is rot13(Gur Tbqsngure) so the word is actually rot13(vaurevgvat).

Comment: @user39583 Ah yes, that would work very nicely, thanks :)

Comment: Great work! Every answer is correct so far

Comment: 29 is rot13(Fvyrag uvyy)

Comment: @Dr.Roggia Indeed, I literally just edited that one in - presumably while you were reading! Good to know someone else agrees with me though, thanks :)

Comment: 33 is incorrect, even though you have the correct highlighted letter! rot(Gb znxr fher guvf jbexrq V unq gb qbhoyr-purpx gung qrpncbqf grpuavpnyyl vapyhqr fdhvq... [vgf abg fdhvq tnzr])

Comment: 38 might be rot13(qnapr qnapr eribyhgvba) ? it's the only thing that comes to my mind with that description, but one letter is missing apparently and idk if it's a misspell by OP or i'm wrong @TwoBitOperation

Comment: @Dr.Roggia That was one of my first thoughts too, wondering if there was an 'S' added to the end or something, but I've just found an option that I think fits really nicely... :)

Comment: @Stiv  You've got 38!

Comment: 32 is almost certainly `NAVZNYPEBFFVAT`

Comment: @IanMacDonald I too [thought that at first](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59745203#59745203), but then it's also #2, and I don't think the same game will appear twice in the puzzle... Still scratching my head on that one!

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion.  Yes, one answer does appear twice as Ian has solved, I should have explained that that was possible in the notes

Comment: All answers are right now, and you have the final meta-answer correct too! Your parsing on the final cryptic is slightly different from what I intended, and my version may become more clear when the rest is filled in. I can point you in the right direction on the last 2 if everyone's stumped, but hopefully someone can chip in as these are slightly lesser known. Awesome job so far!

Comment: @TwoBitOperation I think I see exactly what you're suggesting: (-n)ATION once 'NEEDING' (presumably) is confirmed. Will edit once I have something more substantial to include at the same time :) Thanks for the puzzle - it's been a proper challenge!

Comment: @Stiv Yes, that's the construction I used!  Glad you liked it, it was very fun to make... until near the end when I couldn't bring it all together for the longest time. I'll add small hints for the last two pieces since the meta puzzle is now solved.  Again, great work!

Comment: 31 looks to me like ROT13(Oraql naq gur vax znpuvar)

Comment: @ShadowCat That looks like an excellent shout to me, and would put 3 letters I'd expect to see in those red boxes - thanks! :)

Comment: Perfect!  100% correct